# What is semantic difference between using or omitting verb 持つ as an attributive?

Tags: pragmatics

In the following sentence from [wiki page for 言葉遊び](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89%E9%81%8A%E3%81%B3), what extra information does the verb **持つ** carry?

言葉の**持つ**音の響きやリズムを楽しんだり...

Will the meaning of the sentence change if it is dropped?

言葉の音の響きやリズムを楽しんだり...

Answer (score 1):

That's a tough one...

- Enjoy the sound and rhythm that the words carry
- Enjoy the sound and rhythm of words

Do they make any difference to you?  If they do, perhaps there is some extra information.

Maybe it helps the reader understand リズム is also an attribute of 言葉, by placing some distance between 言葉 and 音. (言葉の"音の響きやリズム", not "言葉の音の響き"やリズム)